# Where is WCF transaction state stored?

Tags: sql-server, wcf, transactions, distributed-transactions

WCF service is configured to use transactions, WCF service method connects to SQL Server and makes changes. Where is state of the transaction stored? What will be if between the database change and the transaction completion this WCF service will be killed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF depends on the built-in .NET System.Transactions capability for transaction management. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733904.aspx) provides a good overview of the WCF transaction capabilities.

If the WCF service fails before committing a distributed transaction then all the changes that are part of that transaction will be rolled back by the distrubuted transaction coordinator. This could be not just the database but other service calls that are enrolled in the same transaction.

Comment: Does System.Trtansactions store the transaction state in memory of WCF service app? Or WCF only propagates the transaction from the client to the database? What will be if the clients makes two WCF service calls (the first to one physical machine, the second - to another), both of them are successful, but before the second service call the first physical machine is destroyed. Will the transaction be commited in this case?

Comment: For distributed transactions, all the enlisted processes have to vote they have successfully completed before the distributed transaction manager commits the individual transactions. This "voting" has to occur before a timeout period set by the distributed transaction manager elapses. In your hypothetical case, the destroyed machine would not be able to vote or the commit would fail causing the distributed transaction manager to rollback all the other pending commits. At least that's how I understand MS DTC works.

Comment: So, does it mean that WCF service holds the state of all uncompleted transactions? And if we place two instances of the service into different physical machines and hide them behind the local balancer, will distributed transactions work? There would be the case when the request is processed by one service instance but the voting WS-Atomic message goes to another service instance.

Comment: No, it is enlisted in a transaction managed by DTC in the same way the database transaction would also be enlisted by DTC. It is DTC that controls the final commit or rollback of each of the enlisted transaction. The [MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd337629(v=ws.10).aspx) has all the details on how the enlisting & voting process works.

Comment: So, if state of the transaction is in DTC, why destroying of the WCF service machine would cause transaction rollback?

Comment: Because DTC would either not be able to perform the final commit or the WCF service would not be able to vote that it has completed successfully and the timeout would occur. In either case, DTC would detect the failure and cause all the other enlisted transactions to rollback.